# Display fixed routes in Drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, routes, drawer, react-navigation

I'm trying to fix the drawer's menu's route names through the entire app. So the drawer should always display the same names even though some other routes are available as well (via the ones displayed in the drawer).

What it looks like now:
[image]

What it should look like:
[image]

Relevant code:

```
const Stack = {
    Login: { screen: Login },
    Overview: { screen: Overview },
    Settings: { screen: Settings },
    Logout: { screen: Logout },
    JobDescription: { screen: JobDescription },
    TaskList: { screen: TaskList },
};

const DrawerRoutes = {
    SettingsStack: {
        name: 'SettingsStack',
        screen: StackNavigator(Stack, { initialRouteName: 'Settings' }),
    },
    OverviewStack: {
        name: 'OverviewStack',
        screen: StackNavigator(Stack, { initialRouteName: 'Overview' }),
    },
    LogoutStack: {
        name: 'LogoutStack',
        screen: StackNavigator(Stack, { initialRouteName: 'Logout' }),
    },
};

export const DrawerNavigation = StackNavigator({
    Drawer: {
        name: 'Drawer',
        screen: DrawerNavigator(DrawerRoutes),
    },
    ...Stack,
}, { headerMode: 'none' });
```

Hope it's clear enough! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the `contentComponent` prop of DrawerNavigator solved the issue.
It's as simple as that:

`Drawer: {
        name: 'Drawer',
        screen: DrawerNavigator(DrawerRoutes, {
            contentComponent: DrawerView,
        }),
    },`

Where `DrawerView` is just a custom component with a FlatList.